# Excel: Vertically ordered tables overlap when data changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel workbook that has a bunch of sheets in it. One sheet is a rollup/at-a-glance sheet that contains a bunch of different tables in it. Each table pulls data using a SQL query from a number of DBs. The tables have a number of columns, but few rows, so I want to have them on top of eachother.

The issue is that when I refresh the data in the workbook, if there are new rows in the first table (for eg) it will "overlap" and excel will fail to update the tables.

I would have hoped that the tables would just shift down when new data is added to a table above it, but no such luck by default. Is there any way to get that to happen?

Comment: I've read your synopsis a few times and I don't understand your setup. What do the other sheets have to do with the "rollup sheet"? How are you refreshing the workbook - through SQL queries written in VBA or data connections?

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: I suspect there is no easy solution here - but I'd love to be proven wrong.  I would go back to the SQL queries and add code to restrict e.g. SELECT TOP 5 ...

Comment: @MikeHoney: Something like a SELECT TOP N would work as the tables would never need to expand, so there'd not be any overlap. What I've done in the interim, is I've split the tables into a separate sheet per table. It's definitely not ideal as I don't get all of this information at-a-glance.